# Testing AngularJs' $http.defaults.headers.common if specific header is set

Tags: angularjs

So I'm new to the world of JavaScript and AngularJS and therefor my code is not as good as it should be yet, but it's improving. Nevertheless I started learning and implementing a simple login page with a REST Backend. After the Login-Form is submitted, a authentication-token is returned and set as a default http-header property like this

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = data.authToken;
```

This works fine whenever I test it manually, but that's not the way to go so I'd like to implement a unit-test which checks if the X-AUTH-TOKEN header is set.

Is there a way to check that with $httpBackend? e.g I have the following test:

```
describe('LoginController', function () {
    var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

    // Load our app module definition before each test.
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    // The injector ignores leading and trailing underscores here (i.e. _$httpBackend_).
    // This allows us to inject a service but then attach it to a variable
    // with the same name as the service.
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('LoginController', {$scope: scope}, {$http: $httpBackend}, {$location: null});
    }));

    it('should create an authToken and set it', function () {
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:9000/login', '200').respond(200, '{"authToken":"52d29fd63004c92b972f6b99;65e922bc-5e33-4bdb-9d52-46fc352189fe"}');
        scope.login('200');
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(scope.data.authToken).toBe('52d29fd63004c92b972f6b99;65e922bc-5e33-4bdb-9d52-46fc352189fe');
        expect(scope.loginValidationOverallError).toBe(false);
        expect(scope.status).toBe(200);
    });
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function ($scope, $http, $location) {

        // Login Stuff
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.status = {};
        $scope.loginValidationOverallError = false;
        $scope.login = function (user) {
            $http.post('http://localhost:9000/login', user).success(function (data, status) {

                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.loginValidationOverallError = false;


                console.log($scope.status, $scope.data);
                $http.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = data.authToken;
                $location.path('/user');

            }).error(function (data, status) {
                    console.log(status + ' error');
                    $scope.loginValidationOverallError = true;
                });

        };
        ...
```

I checked the documentation at [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) but am not sure if the last test is actually applicable to my code (and how that code actually tests something)

```
it('should send auth header', function() {
    var controller = createController();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/add-msg.py', undefined, function(headers) {
        // check if the header was send, if it wasn't the expectation won't
        // match the request and the test will fail
        return headers['Authorization'] == 'xxx';
    }).respond(201, '');

    $rootScope.saveMessage('whatever');
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and I finally solved it. It was very tricky

Souce code for **AuthenticationService.login()** function

```
$http.post(...)
  .success(function(data) {
     ...
     $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = data.oauth_token;
   });
```

Test code

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_,AuthenticationService) {
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $authenticationService = AuthenticationService;
}));

it('should login successfully with correct parameter', inject(function($http) {
// Given
...
...
var fakeResponse = {
  access_token: 'myToken'
}

$httpBackend.expectPOST('oauth/token',urlEncodedParams, function(headers) {
      return headers['Content-Type'] ===  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
}).respond(200, fakeResponse);

// When
$authenticationService.login(username,password); 


// Then
$httpBackend.flush();
expect($http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']).toBe('myToken');
```

The **trick** here is that the default header is set on the **real $http service**, not the mocked $httpBackend. That's why you should inject the real $http service

I've tried testing the $httpBackend but got an "undefined" error because $httpBackend does not have 'defaults' property